# How to add views to Fragment B that are not involved in a shared element transition from Fragment A?

Tags: android, android-studio, shared-element-transition

So I have a recycler view item that looks like this:
[Transition View Start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SCXT.png)

And I want to end up with this:
[Transition View End](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMpst.png)

The problem I keep getting is an index out-of-bounds exception. So the start has 6 views that transition and all have the appropriate transition name based on a unique id.
The end view has all 6 but 2 more, the small water and thermometer images. Those two have no transition names. Yet they keep getting added to a list that stores the transition views. The following code is in DefaultSpecialEffectsController.java - line 701

```
void captureTransitioningViews(ArrayList<View> transitioningViews, View view) {
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        if (!transitioningViews.contains(view)
                && ViewCompat.getTransitionName(view) != null) {
            transitioningViews.add(view);
        }
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
        int count = viewGroup.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                captureTransitioningViews(transitioningViews, child);
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (!transitioningViews.contains(view)) {
            transitioningViews.add(view);
        }
    }
}
```

And the index out of bounds occurs here FragmentTranstionImpl.java - line 176

```
void setNameOverridesReordered(final View sceneRoot,
        final ArrayList<View> sharedElementsOut, final ArrayList<View> sharedElementsIn,
        final ArrayList<String> inNames, final Map<String, String> nameOverrides) {
    final int numSharedElements = sharedElementsIn.size();
    final ArrayList<String> outNames = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numSharedElements; i++) {
        final View view = sharedElementsOut.get(i);
        final String name = ViewCompat.getTransitionName(view);
        outNames.add(name);
        if (name == null) {
            continue;
        }
        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(view, null);
        final String inName = nameOverrides.get(name);
        for (int j = 0; j < numSharedElements; j++) {
            if (inName.equals(inNames.get(j))) {
                ViewCompat.setTransitionName(sharedElementsIn.get(j), name);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to add the two small icons and in general any view, without them being in the starting transition view in recycler view in Fragment A?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Fragments , specifically fixed in [Fragment 1.3.5](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.5). You'll need to upgrade to that version.

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.5"
```